# How to restrict write access to a Linux directory by process attributes?

Tags: c, linux, security, permissions

We've got a situation where it would be advantageous to limit write access to a logging directory to a specific subset of user processes. These particular processes (say, for example, telnet and the like) have been modified by us to generate a logging record whenever a significant user action takes place (like a remote connection, etc). What we do not want is for the user to manually create these records by copying and editing existing logging records.

`syslog` comes close but still allows the user to generate spurious records, `SELinux` seems plausible but has a terrible reputation of being an unmanageable beast.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a local logging daemon as root. Have it listen on an Unix domain socket (typically `/var/run/my-logger.socket` or similar).

Write a simple logging library, where event messages are sent to the locally running daemon via the Unix domain socket. With each event, also send the process credentials via an ancillary message. See [man 7 unix](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) for details.

When the local logging daemon receives a message, it checks for the ancillary message, and if none, discards the message. The `uid` and `gid` of the credentials tell exactly who is running the process that has sent the logging request; these are verified by the kernel itself, so they cannot be spoofed (unless you have root privileges).

Here comes the clever bit: the daemon also checks the `PID` in the credentials, and based on its value, `/proc/PID/exe`. It is a symlink to the actual process binary being executed by the process that send the message, something the user cannot fake. To be able to fake a message, they'd have to overwrite the actual binaries with their own, and that should require root privileges.

(There is a possible race condition: a user may craft a special program that does the same, and immediately `exec()`s a binary they know to be allowed. To avoid that race, you may need to have the daemon respond after checking the credentials, and the logging client send another message (with credentials), so the daemon can verify the credentials are still the same, and the `/proc/PID/exe` symlink has not changed. I would personally use this to check the message veracity (by the logger asking for confirmation for the event, with a random cookie, and have the requester respond with both the checksum and the cookie whether the event checksum is correct. Including the random cookie should make it impossible to stuff the confirmation in the socket queue before `exec()`.)

With the `pid` you can do also further checks. For example, you can trace the process parentage to see how the human user has connected by tracking parents till you detect a login via ssh or console. It's a bit tedious, since you'll need to parse `/proc/PID/stat` or `/proc/PID/status` files, and nonportable. OSX and BSDs have a sysctl call you can use to find out the parent process ID, so you *can* make it portable by writing a platform-specific `parent_process_of(pid_t pid)` function.

This approach will make sure your logging daemon knows exactly 1) which executable the logging request came from, and 2) which user (and how connected, if you do the process tracing) ran the command.

As the local logging daemon is running as root, it can log the events to file(s) in a root-only directory, and/or forward the messages to a remote machine.

Obviously, this is not exactly lightweight, but assuming you have less than a dozen events per second, the logging overhead should be completely neglible.

Comment: Using a daemon is a bit heavyweight, we went with a setuid binary which checked /proc/$PPID/exe to ensure that the logging requests only came from our limited subset of application binaries

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: If you use the same strategy (create an Unix domain socket using `socketpair()` inherited by the setuid binary in say descriptor 3), then you are perfectly fine. Otherwise, you have a problem. `PPID` survives `exec()`. This means that if the user writes a program that forks, exec'ing any allowed system binary, and the child waits for the `/proc/PPID/exe` to change then execs the setuid logger binary, the logger binary will think the event came from a system binary. The fix is a conversation (Log this. This? Yes), with credential passing and checking both times.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment, once the exec occurs, control is transferred completely to the system binary, the parent process cannot subsume the attributes of the child, that said, your answer is detailed and quite close to the final approach, so you get the answer :)

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: Consider a simple program that `fork()`s a child. The `PPID` in the child == `PID` of the original process. The original process `exec()`s a valid system binary. Its `PID` stays unchanged. The child waits until it sees `/proc/PPID/exe` change to point to the system binary, then `exec()`s the setuid logger binary. (It can even send `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP` to the parent, to pause it.) Your logger binary sees that `/proc/PPID/exe` points to a valid system binary, and accepts the event. Do you need an example program that does exactly this, so you can test/verify?

Answer (score 1):

Generally there's two ways of doing this. One, run these processes as `root` and write protect the directory (mentioned mainly for historical purposes). Then no one but root can write there. The second, and more secure is to run them as another user (not `root`) and give that user, but no one else, write access to the log directory.

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned this in the answer, the first way is basically mentioned for historical reasons. It's how people used to do things before people realized that setting things up suid root/running things as root was a bad idea.

Comment: We used a suid approach but limited logging requests based on /proc/$PPID/exe

Answer (score 0):

The approach we went with was to use a setuid binary to allow write access to the logging directory, the binary was executable by all users but would only allow a log record to be written if the parent process path as defined by /proc/$PPID/exe matched the subset of modified binary paths we placed on the system.